# How blink single character without delay() method on LCD using Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, delay, lcd

So, I want to write method than can provide blinking on LCD in special possition a specail value without using delay() method.
I wrote the next method:

```
void blink(int cursorIndex, int val) {
   lcd.setCursor(cursorIndex, 0);

   if (millis() - blinkTime > 1000) {
      blinkTime = millis();
      printValOnLCD(val);
   } else {
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.print(" ");
   }
}
```

But it work not in that case that I exectly need.
It blink only one time when `millis() - blinkTime > 1000` in other cases it show __ .

How can I provide one blinking per one second??

Comment: You need to *toggle* your state each time the condition is true. So write a function `toggle(bool OnOff)` and think how to implement it.

Comment: If it's more than 500ms print it, if it's less than 500ms don't print it, and if it's more than 1000ms then reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following code should let the LCD blink once per second. The blinking speed can be changed by changing the `blinkSpeed_ms` variable.

```
void blink(int cursorIndex, int val) {
   lcd.setCursor(cursorIndex, 0);
   blinkSpeed_ms = 1000; //This variable defines the blinking speed

   if ((millis() - blinkTime > blinkSpeed_ms) && (millis() - blinkTime < blinkSpeed_ms * 2)) {
      printValOnLCD(val);
   } else if(millis() - blinkTime > (blinkSpeed_ms * 2)) {
      blinkTime = millis()
   }else {
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.print(" ");
   }
}
```